# Crystal Reports 7 - How to accumulate values from a supressed entry

Tags: crystal-reports, report

sorry for annoy u once more =P

I have a report where i must show a detailed bill list. Then, i have a total for the bills and a total for the canceled bills. The problem is that i'm using a rule to suppress the bills that are marked as canceled from the list, because i don't want to show them... But i still want to show the total for the cancelled ones. So, as they are suppressed, i can't manipulate their values. How can i proceed to hide the unwanted bills and still keep track of their values do sum?

Comment: Something to note: Although a formula field or report section may be suppressed, that does not mean that the containing code will not be evaluated. If you try to assign a variable in a suppressed section, the assignment *will* be carried out.

Comment: After a while i figured that out. ^_^ So now i got the result i expected. U guys from stackoverflow are the best! =P Hugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different approaches you could take:

- Use a subreport to calculate the cancelled bills total
- Modify your report to not suppress cancelled bills then us conditional formulas/running total to calculate bills vs. cancelled bills
- Use a sql expression to calculate the cancelled bills total

There are probably others- but these are the first i thought of.

Comment: I'm a very noob in the world of crystal reports... Could u just tell me the basic steps to implement a sub-report?

Comment: Or if i choose not to supress cancelled bills, how can i avoid them to be shown?

Comment: @GiordanoGiuliano IMO, the subreport is the worst approach of those mentioned. I'd go with the Running Total instead if you're new to CR.